# how to add an object to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I created three class which are `PersonalData`, `Student`, `Course`.
I try to create `addStudent(Student) :boolean` method to add in `Student[] studentArray = new Student[capacity];` this array.

To do that I wrote this code:

```
public boolean addStudent(Student newStudent){
  numberOfStudents=0;
  for(int i=0; i< capacity; i++){
    studentArray[i]= new Student[];
  }
}
```

I am new at Java so I don't know if it is right or not?

Plus, every student has an unique id. I defined it like that `private long id;` in the `Student` Class.

In the `addStudent(Student)` method I want to check if the student is already in course or not. To do that I am gonna use `id` because every student has a unique id. The problem is that I don't know where I can use `if` statements and in where I can use `return` statements.

Comment: I would suggest reading a good intro to java book.

Answer (score 4):

1. You pass a student Object `newStudent` and do nothing with it.
2. You - apparently - try to create a new Student Object using the syntax for array creation, which in your case wont even compile because 1, you don't pass a size an 2, the type of studentArray[i] and new Student[] are not compatible even if yo happened to pass the size for array creation. You probably wanted to use the constructor `new Student()` which is not necessary because you already pass an object of Student.

Try something like this:

```
public boolean addStudent(Student newStudent){
    if(numberOfStudents < capacity) {
        studentArray[numberOfStudents++] = newStudent;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @user3075117 Cool, you're welcome, you might then mark the answer as accepted am probably up-vote it as well :)

Comment: Thank you for your up-vote. I also want to up-vote for yours but i still have 12 reputation so I cant.

Comment: hi @A4L again:) It works bur I also try to check if newStudents is already exist in the array.  I tried like that (newStudent instanceof Student) but ofcourse it didnt work well. Every student has a unique id so I should check if the newStudent.getID is already an object's id in the array. Any idea??